# Apple Health Data: Accessing Without An iOS App

Tags: ios, mobile, apple-watch, healthkit

**Is there a way to access apple health data without using an iOS application?**

Hi everyone ! If anyone can help me, I’m hoping to ask a question about accessing Apple Health Data.

From what I know, we can access Apple Health Data with at least 3 ways:

1. A custom iOS app
2. An existing iOS health export app like QS Access
3. An Apple shortcuts to periodically export health data

Are there any other ways to access Apple Health Data, especially without an iOS application? I don't know if this would work, but maybe a mobile web application can also query the user for the apple health permissions? If anyone has the time to spare additional insight, I would really appreciate it.

Thank you so much ! I hope you have a great day !

Comment: This question is better asked on [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com) as it's not actually about software development. You're more likely to get an answer there.

Comment: AFAIK the only way to get Health data is using HealthKit. If you want to avoid Swift/ObjC development, you can wrap HealthKit using whatever your stack allows you, but this must happen as an application.